# Docker ARG not working as expected and prints empty when echoed

Tags: docker

This `ARG` is driving me crazy. A shame for docker developers who do not understand what a good DX can be.

This is my requirement. I need to build a docker file. The build command is inside an `if` statement:

```
if [[ some_condition ]]; then
    docker build -t tag --build-arg AuthSecret=value1 --build-arg KeycloakClientSecret=value2 --build-arg KeycloakIssuer=value3
else
   docker build -t tag
fi
```

So, inside my `Dockerfile` I have multiple build stages (multiple `FROM`). I need my args to be available to all of them. The [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) says that you should define the args before the first `FROM` and then redefine them after each `FROM` with an empty value.

```
ARG AuthSecret=some_value
ARG KeycloakClientSecret=another_value
ARG KeycloakIssuer=https://accounts.example.com/realms/Production

FROM custom/image:latest as builder

ARG AuthSecret
ARG KeycloakClientSecret
ARG KeycloakIssuer

RUN echo "$AuthSecret from builder" 
RUN echo "$KeycloakClientSecret from builder"
RUN echo "$KeycloakIssuer from builder"

ENV AUTH_SECRET $AuthSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET $KeycloakClientSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_ISSUER $KeycloakIssuer

COPY . /

RUN chmod 777 /Build \
    && bash /Build

FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim as runner

ARG AuthSecret
ARG KeycloakClientSecret
ARG KeycloakIssuer

RUN echo "$AuthSecret from runner" 
RUN echo "$KeycloakClientSecret from runner"
RUN echo "$KeycloakIssuer from runner"

ENV AUTH_SECRET $AuthSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET $KeycloakClientSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_ISSUER $KeycloakIssuer
```

And all of the `echo` commands print empty value.

Comment: The build commands are invalid, neither of them include a context. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that anything you provide as an `ENV` value can be trivially retrieved by `docker inspect`ing the resulting image; you probably do not want to push any sort of secret through your image build this way.  Consider using a `docker run -e` option to provide an environment value when you run the container instead, or bind-mounting a configuration file with secrets at run time.